# Spring Bean Custom Scope JMS

Tags: java, spring, scope, spring-jms

I am using Spring Framework to **concurrently** consume messages off of a JMS queue using a **DefaultMessageListenerContainer**.  I want the ability to create new instances of the beans that are autowired for each message that comes in.  I thought setting the scope="prototype" would work but it doesn't seem to do the job.  Does anybody know of a **custom bean scope that would create new instances per JMS message**? Much like the "request" scope does for HTTP Requests?

I realize that I could make com.sample.TestListener "BeanFactoryAware" and then just do a getBean("foo") in my onMessage but I wanted to avoid putting the Spring dependency into my code.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Example below, I want a new instances of "com.sample.Foo" and all beans injected into it each time a message comes in.

```
<bean id="consumer"
    class="com.sample.TestListener">
    <constructor-arg ref="foo" />
</bean> 

<!--Configures the Spring Message Listen Container. Points to the Connection 
    Factory, Destination, and Consumer -->
<bean id="MessageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="CachedConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="Topic" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="consumer" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="10"/> 
</bean> 

<bean id="foo" class="com.sample.Foo">
    <property name="x" ref="xx" />
    <property name="y" ref="yy" /> 
    <property name="z" ref="zz" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I find you post hrlpfull for me. Please explain why `prototype`doesn't work, and why you want a sepate bean per jms message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty easy to write a custom scope to do this...

```
public class CustomScope implements Scope, BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        String name = "myScope";

        beanFactory.registerScope(name, this);

        Assert.state(beanFactory instanceof BeanDefinitionRegistry,
                "BeanFactory was not a BeanDefinitionRegistry, so CustomScope cannot be used.");
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;

        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            BeanDefinition definition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
            if (name.equals(definition.getScope())) {
                BeanDefinitionHolder proxyHolder = ScopedProxyUtils.createScopedProxy(new BeanDefinitionHolder(definition, beanName), registry, false);
                registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, proxyHolder.getBeanDefinition());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
        return objectFactory.getObject(); // a new one every time
    }

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveContextualObject(String arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}


public class Foo implements MessageListener {

    private Bar bar;

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println(bar.getId());
    }

}
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FooTests {

    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Message message = mock(Message.class);
        foo.onMessage(message);
        foo.onMessage(message);
    }

}
```

and a sample context...

```
<bean class="foo.CustomScope" />

<bean id="baz" class="foo.BazImpl" scope="myScope" />

<bean id="bar" class="foo.BarImpl" scope="myScope">
    <property name="baz" ref="baz" />
</bean>

<bean id="foo" class="foo.Foo">
    <property name="bar" ref="bar" />
</bean>
```

**Note:** with this simple scope, you have to put all the referenced beans in the scope as well (bar **and** baz above). You can make all the referenced beans inherit the scope, but it takes some work. That said - there's an example of how to do it in spring-batch's StepScope.

**Note#2** this will get a new instance for every method call. If you call multiple methods you'll get a new bean for each call. If you want to scope it to allow all calls within onMessage to use the same instance, you'll need to add some more tricks.

**EDIT:**
Here are some updates to support multiple calls to an instance within the onMessage()...

```
private final ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> holder = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>>();

...

@Override
public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
    Map<String, Object> cache = this.holder.get();
    if (cache == null) {
        cache = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        this.holder.set(cache);
    }
    Object object = cache.get(name);
    if (object == null) {
        object = objectFactory.getObject();
        cache.put(name, object);
    }
    return object;
}

public void clearCache() {
    this.holder.remove();
}
```

Now, you **do** have to clear the cache...

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        System.out.println(bar.getId());
        System.out.println(bar.getId());
    }
    finally {
        this.scope.clearCache();
    }
}
```

But even that could be done in an AOP @After advice, to keep the listener totally clean.

Comment: Of course, it's better to use stateless beans to avoid having to do things like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sample code! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @GaryRussell How'd your solution work if the bean being created had `@Autowired` dependencies? This is where I find all custom scope solutions falling short because they demonstrate creating a basic POJO almost non-existent in production. Your solution is better that most because you implement `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, even though I think for separation of responsibility it might be better to have separate classes.

Comment: See the [Spring Documentation about scoped beans as dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection).

Comment: @GaryRussell Are you referring to this part? [Customizing beans using a BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp)? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842242/how-to-instantiate-spring-bean-with-custom-scope-and-autowired-dependencies?noredirect=1#comment49729922_30842242) is my use case.

Comment: No; I'm referring to the `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` which is what the link points to. Each time the autowired field is referenced, your custom scope's `get()` method is called to lookup the instance based on some criteria.

Comment: I understand I can look up the dependencies (though unsure how, a scope isn't a bean, perhaps I need to pass application context during instantiation?). What I don't understand is how to inject those dependencies into my bean if those're marked `@Autowired`? Or are you saying the custom scoped bean shouldn't have `@Autowired` dependencies?
I don't want to hijack this thread, we can continue this discussion on my question if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleThreadScope implementation which come with Spring

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html